# To run this agent you must have at leat one document selected

Tags: lotus-notes, agent

[image]

I am running the agent without any documents in NSF because it fetches the data from an SQL DB. I don't have SQL access. I am running the agent to export all the form names and fields, view names, and their corresponding columns. There is no error in the code. Can't we run an agent without any documents?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set agent's property "Target" to "None".

[image]